# K negative edges - single source shortest path

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

I've managed to solve the problem finding all single source shortest paths when there's exactly one negative edge using dijkstra.

Now i'm trying to face a new problem, how to find all shortest paths from a given source when there are exactly K negative edges using dijkstra only (Not bellman ford). (k is known).

Can't really think of a good way to do it.

any suggestions?

Comment: What if there is a negative cycle? There won't be a shortest path. There is not much point in wanting to use the wrong tools for the job, you're like trying to tighten a screw using a fork.

Comment: Well, I know that there's a way to solve that using Dijkstra only.. You can also assume that there are no negative cycles

Comment: Related? http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/using-dijkstras-algorithm-with-negative-edges

Comment: What's about to make all the edge positive? If you know the most negative edge you can always add this value + 1 to all the edge wieght and then the assumption of dist(s, vi ) ≤ dist(s, vi+1 ) for 0 ≤ i < k will be still true. So in that situation the distance between two edge will be computed as dist(s, vi ) - (mose negative edge) + 1 instead of dist(s, vi ). Of course you will have to found this edge before and you will have to add this to the performance.

Comment: @user688877, that won't work. Imagine A->B (1), B->C (-5), A->C (1). A-B-C is the optimal path from A to C with weight -4. You add 6 to all weights. Now A-C is the optimal path with weight 7 (compared to A-B-C's 8) because the A-B-C path got 6 added twice, while A-C got it added only once.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a nondirectional graph, there is no single shortest path because even with a single negative edge, you could just go back and forth on that negative edge and have an infinite number of paths of negative infinity.

However, assuming a directional graph with no negative cycles, you could use Breadth First Search and keep track of both the negative edges you've already hit and the shortest path to each node you've discovered so far. If you see a node you've already visited, you only go there again if it would be better than the previous path you took to get there.

Since there are no negative cycles the algorithm must terminate. After the algorithm terminates the target node should have the best path that was used to get there.